# Highcharts flagged as 'Invalid SecureWindow API' in Lightning CLI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, highcharts

I am using HighCharts for drawing some reports in Lightning Component. HighCharts is loaded from static resource and all expected functionalities are working fine with Locker Service ON. This is a part of AppExchange solution. As a preparation for security review when the code is scanned with Lightning CLI, Highcharts initialization in code is flagged as 'Invalid SecureWindow API'. I am looking for any workarounds avoid the CLI scan flagging.

> error  secure-window  Invalid SecureWindow API
>   Line:113:31
>   YTDChartObj = new **Highcharts**.Chart({
>                                    ^
>
> error     no-undef    'Highcharts' is not defined
>   Line:191:51
>
> ((**Highcharts**.theme && **Highcharts**.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">' +
>   **Highcharts**.numberFormat(YTDBooking, 0, ',', ',') + '
> ' +

```
                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 2):

The CLI (its just using eslint with a custom rules config BTW) currently has no visibility into the static resources that you are including in your components and unfortunately defaults to this rather distressing looking error message. I believe if you update to the latest version of the CLI these have been toned down a bit to warnings. Also, you can configure the CLI locally to ignore specific things.

Comment: Thanks Doug for sharing the info. I hope we can safely ignore this warning as of now and wont be flagged by the Security review team when submitted for AppExchange review.